# Converting a Dictionary with a value of [NSNull null] to JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to use this code:

```
NSDictionary *innerMessage 
      = @{@"nonce":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:nonce],
          @"payload":@{@"login": [NSNull null]}};

NSError * err;
NSData * innerMessageData = [NSJSONSerialization 
     dataWithJSONObject:innerMessage options:0  
     error:&err];
```

to create a `JSON` object with the following structure:

```
{
    "apikey": "e418f5b4a15608b78185540ef583b9fc",
    "signature": "FN6/9dnMfLh3wZj+cAFr82HcSvmwuniMQqUlRxSQ9WxRqFpYrjY2xlvDzLC5+qSZAHts8R7KR7HbjiI3SzVxHg==",
    "message":{
        "nonce": 12, 
        "payload": {
            "Login": {}
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is the actual result which I get:

```
{"nonce":1398350092512,"payload":{"login":null}}
```

- Why is `[NSNull null]` in my dictionary not being converted to `{}`?
- How would I need to change my code to get the correct `JSON`
  structure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to

```
NSDictionary *innerMessage = @{
                                   @"nonce":@12,
                                   @"payload":@{@"login": @{}}
                              };

NSError * err;
NSData * innerMessageData = [NSJSONSerialization 
     dataWithJSONObject:innerMessage options:0  
     error:&err];
```

This will create the desired response

```
{
    nonce = 12,
    payload =  {
        login = {}
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSNull` is suppose to become `null` in the JSON.

If you want an empty dictionary in the JSON (`{}`) you should use an empty dictionary - `@{}`.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a perfectly valid JSON value; what were you expecting? How should `NSJSONSerialization` know that you wanted `[NSNull null]` to be converted to an empty object? (For that matter, why wouldn’t nulls be converted to an empty array, an empty list, or numeric zero?)

The solution is to process your `innerMessage` before you serialize it, replacing any instances of `[NSNull null]` with `@{}` (or, equivalently, `[NSDictionary dictionary]`).